# Symfony2 doctrine:schema:update keeps updating

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've just added a new attribute in my model:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="has_donation", type="boolean", options ={"default":false})
*/
private $hasDonation;
```

And then I tried running:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

which gave me the following result:

```
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "1" queries were executed
```

The problem is that each time I run the `schema:update` command, I get the same result - without making any changes to my entities. Any idea why? Thanks!

**Update**
Here's the out for `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`:

```
ALTER TABLE Clinic CHANGE has_donation has_donation TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you fix it?

Comment: I don't remember precisely how I managed to fix it but I now set-up default values in a different way: private $hasDonation = false; instead  of using the options parameter when declaring the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try deleting cache.

Then, try `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to see what updated.
These options with `"default": false` differences are not recorded sometimes. At least on PostgreSQL we use.

You might need them to run them manually.

---

Tip from our workflow:

1) we setup entities

2) then run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

3) then run migrations that add there details that are not transformed to database

Answer (score 3):

I can assume that this issue arises because of usage of illegal or irrelevant mapping information.

In case of the question author, the option `"default":false` was illegal.

I had same issue with code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     type="boolean",
 *     nullable=false,
 *     options={"unsigned":true, "comment":"Is file uploaded manually?"}
 * )
 */
protected $manual = false;
```

In my case the option `"unsigned":true` was irrelevant. After removing this option, I got the code working.